# Is there a way to use jests toHaveBeenCalledWith to check arguments array length?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Function would be called with:

`{ items: [1, 2, 3]}`

```js
expect(mockedFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        items: expect.toBeLengthOf(3) // Pseudocode, this function does not exist here
      }),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.mock` object](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-property) on mocked function has `.calls` list on it. So

```
expect(
  mockedFunction.mock.calls[mockedFunction.mock.calls.length - 1][0].items
).toHaveLength(3);
```

will validate length of `items` property on first(0-based numeration) argument for last time(`mockedFunction.mock.calls.length - 1`) it has been called.

Also you may consider using [`expect.anything()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectanything) as a placeholder:

```
expect(mockedFunction).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
    items: [expect.anything(), expect.anything(), expect.anything()]
  })
)
```

But it may be better to use a mock and return the same values consistently - this will allow you to validate the contents of the array rather than just its length